# Debian: The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

Whenever trying to install some programs from source, or specifically running apt update, I receive this message:

```
E: The repository 'http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I started getting this after adding the architecture i386. Without it, I would not be able to install the proprietary Nvidia driver, and Steam client would not start at all.
This is what my `/etc/apt/sources.list` reads:

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

####stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You’ve got both `stretch-updates` and `stretch/updates`, but the latter doesn’t exist any more (at least on the mirror you’re using). You should remove the references to `stretch/updates`, or — if you’re expecting the `stretch/updates` lines to provide security updates — [replace them with](https://www.debian.org/security/)

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

In late April 2023, the Stretch repositories were removed from the main mirrors, so you’ll need to switch to `archive.debian.org`; see [apt-get update failed to fetch debian amd64 packages while building dockerfile from maven:3.5.2-jdk-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743839/86440) and [Security repo for Debian stretch not working anymore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/744401/86440) for details.

Comment: i removed it, and it solved the issue, but its odd because in the Software & Sources program, stretch/release (with the slash) refers to the security updates of stretch.

Comment: Right, but that’s from `https://security.debian.org`, not your local mirror. (And it’s `stretch/updates` , not `stretch/release`; see [here](http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/) for the `Release` file and [the corresponding instructions](https://www.debian.org/security/).)

Comment: `http://archive.debian.org/debian-security` is the new security url

Comment: @casey yes, as [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/744408/86440) (follow the links in the post above).

Answer (score 32):

Run the following command and it should be fixed

```
echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or change the repository website `deb.debian.org` to `archive.debian.org` by running:

```
sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and if there is security too (security.debian.org) then:

```
sed -i s/security.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

[the reasons](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/03/msg00006.html)

Comment: Interesting. Also, at the [official Debian packages website](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages), there is not information about `stretch` anymore, one week ago (April, 2023) I got the stretch versions for each package that I filter.

Comment: This issue bites me today as well...

Comment: @AliRNazari based on the [archive Debian mirror](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/), there is not exist the `stretch-security` directory (yet), assuming that there is not usefull, I edit your answer instead of pulbish a new one.

Comment: @FrancoGil You are right. Thanks for the edit. o/

Comment: @FrancoGil is the man! for those on older gen of CircleCi image like me ```sudo echo deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free" | sudo -E tee /etc/apt/sources.list```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Would you mind explaining what you're actually doing here resp. why this entry is required in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by now?

Comment: @NotX In March of 2023, the Debian 9 `stretch` was copied to the archive site, and about a month later (in April), it was removed from the main Debian repository sites. [Announcement on Debian-devel-announce mailing list.](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/03/msg00006.html) That caused the original repository entries in `sources.list` to stop working. If you still want to download packages for Debian 9, you'll have to switch to using the archive site instead.