# Getting "This repository does not have a release file" on freshly installed Debian 9.1 with KDE

Tags: debian, security, apt, package-management, kde

So I just freshly installed Debian 9.1 with KDE and I'm getting the following errors after changing my sources.list file with `sudo kwrite`:

> W: The repository [...] does not have a release file.
>   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefor potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>   N: Error fetching from [ip/updates/contrib/source/Sources] 404 Not found
>   E: Some index files couldn't be downloaded they got ignored or old ones were used instead.

This question is related to [this one here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371890/debian-the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file) but setting it to `stretch/updates` doesn't help in my case.

I get these errors with all of the many sources I tried so far.

I could run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` after some changes to the file; however 2 packages have been held back: firefox-esr.
Furthermore once after booting up it only showed blue but I could open the task manager. And once it froze when I tried to shutdown at the shutdown menu. Furthermore I also got
`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'` and
`QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/0, 0 instead of 1000` earlier - but this might be another question.
Note that when I verified the DVD in the installer it told me it was fine, that I'm still new to Linux and that I'm having these errors after a fresh install.

Comment: ...So what does your sources list say?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now after:

- Changing the sources file by duplicating the below lines with one of the pairs saying `stretch-updates` instead of `stretch`
- running `apt-get install firefox-esr`

---

Prior I only commented out the CD sources and added a source in the same way as [here](https://linuxconfig.org/debian-apt-get-jessie-sources-list), like:

`deb http://ftp.id.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib`
`deb-src http://ftp.id.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib`

which I changed to stretch/updates which didn't help nor did changing the mirror.

For the bluescreen and freezes I created a separate question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381941/debian-9-1-with-kde-regularly-freezes-and-sometimes-shows-bluescreen)