# Debian 9.1 with KDE regularly freezes and sometimes shows bluescreen

Tags: debian, kde, freeze

So I'm running a 64bit machine running Debian 9.1 with KDE.
Sadly it regularly freezes so that I can't do nothing but moving the mouse; sound keeps running.
Furthermore sometimes it shows a blue screen.
I did not have these problems earlier with Debian 9.0 and Cinnamon.

How can I find out what's causing this? What are relevant logs? Could my NVIDIA graphics card or my RAM be causing this? I'm still new to GNU/Linux and any help is welcome.

Edit: it's gone now. I only had it the early days after installation.

Answer (score -2):

FAÇA BUSCA DE NOS PROGRAMAS E UPDATE DE REPOSITORIO E UPGRADE E INSTALE KDEMULTIMEDIA PELO SYNAPTICS,  NA CONFIGURAÇAO DE VIDEO COLOQUE EM XRENDER PARA A EXECUÇAO SEM OPENGL, REINICIE O SISTEMA E HABILITE NOVAMENTE A OPÇAO OPENGL EM 2.0 OU 2.1  (INTERMEDIARIO ENTRE XRENDER E 3.1) E TUDO FICA NORMALIZADO

---

Google Translate (unmodified from Portuguese):

SEARCH FOR UPDATE AND REPLACE PROGRAMS AND UPDATE AND INSTALL KDEMULTIMEDIA BY SYNAPTICS, IN THE VIDEO SETTING PLACE IN XRENDER FOR EXECUTION WITHOUT OPENGL, RESTART THE SYSTEM AND REPLACE THE OPENGL OPTION IN 2.0 OR 2.1 (INTERMEDIARY BETWEEN XRENDER AND 3.1) AND EVERYTHING IS STANDARDIZED.

Comment: Este site é apenas em inglês. E o uso de caracteres capitais é considerado grosseiro.