# How to open listchanges.db file in Debian?

Tags: debian, sqlite

I'm trying to open the `listchanges.db` file located under `/var/lib/apt/` with `DB Browser for SQLite` under Debian 9.1 with KDE and it says: "Invalid file format."
How can I open it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Where is this file? What does it come from? What made you think it is a SQL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listchanges.db`, as used by `apt-listchanges`, is a Berkeley DB database, not a SQLite database:

```
$ file /var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 8, native byte-order)
```

You can dump its contents (albeit not in a particularly human-readable format) using

```
db5.3_dump /var/lib/apt/listchanges.db | less
```

For human-readable output, use

```
apt-listchanges --dump-seen
```

Comment: Thanks. It's very short and there's nothing of interest in there. I thought it was for a file history / changelog of the _sources.list_ file because of its name and as there's also a listchanges.conf file in the same directory as that file. (I was interested in this as I wanted to see what exactly I had in there earlier for [my question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381567/getting-this-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-on-freshly-installed-debi); it would be useful.)

Comment: It gets bigger, at least if you use `apt-listchanges` ;-). If you want to keep a history of `sources.list`, use `etckeeper`; but that won’t help you find older contents (older than when you start using it).